# OpenMPI on Cygwin terminates without output

Tags: cygwin, openmpi

I installed Cygwin 64-bit 2.831 on Windows 8 and I installed the built-in OpenMPI 1.7.4-1 packages. 
Now whenever I invoke any OpemMPI program (e.g. mpirun, mpicc, mpic++, ompi_info), it immediately terminates without any output. It doesn't even report problems in the command line arguments. Any solution or explanation is much appreciated.

Thank you

**UPDATE**: Apparently, it is a 64-bit issue; mpic++ seems to work on 32-bit Cygwin.
Running `gdb mpic++` on 64-bit Cygwin gives the following output:

```
Starting program: /usr/bin/opal_wrapper
[New Thread 3544.0x6f8]
warning: `/cygdrive/c/Windows/SYSTEM32/wow64.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-    64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/wow64win.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `/cygdrive/c/Windows/system32/wow64cpu.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not compatible with target architecture i386.
dll path too long
dll path too long
dll path too long
dll path too long
warning: `/usr/bin/cygwin1.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not    compatible with target architecture i386.
warning: `/usr/bin/cygwin1.dll': Shared library architecture i386:x86-64 is not   compatible with target architecture i386.
[Inferior 1 (process 3544) exited with code 030000000173]
```

Running `strace mpic++` gives:

```
strace.exe: error creating process mpic++, (error 2)
```

Comment: Use `gdb` and `strace` to debug. Provide this debug info in question.